# Exception thrown by async function not getting caught by catch block

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have Typescript code that looks something like this:

```
    myFunction = async (param: string) : Promise<string, null> => {
        //some synchronous code here
        try {
            await anotherAsyncFnWhichisThrowingAnException();
        }
        catch(err) {
            //this code is not reached even on an exception
        }
    }
```

The code inside the catch block is not getting executed even when anotherAsyncFnWhichisThrowingAnException throws an excpetion. Why is it so and how can I catch this exception?

Comment: can you show the code in `anotherAsyncFnWhichisThrowingAnException`? Like from where it is thrown to (this here) where it should get caught.

Comment: @Thomas This is my code: https://www.ideone.com/gF0Vfa

Comment: OK, what's the error? Are you sure that the error is thrown in `getAsync()` and not before the `try ... `?

Comment: [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2BdyAWApgE4CC40AYhAOr6pT0gAq+x6A7qhAOakQBRAB5RCABzSYAFMABcIZMW48AlDADeAKBgxUcGDJgBeEzABERADaX0Zldo0OdBdhxgRCbgcXbEpZl047AG4HAF8HYkJkBGIsAAV2AFtUEEIAOiiQdEsAN0IZFVCIzShMBRgksEokKEksI2wKWCkxYGJgJNkYBSVeNW7E9BS0gB5e5QA+Y2mtHWdiMEd5lewOYFRkbFwCEnJIKGo6BiZWV2V+YVEJDAh-KxsQpxgIlahgZEYpEmJunDA1HNVjoyhBspYMjYeP5vL4YO9PkQACZmAA0MB+RWer3mURicXMoEUyjMxU0miqNRQt38bQ6SRCQA] (Works on "my" machine) (although had to remove `null` from the return definition)

Comment: Your code is fine, so the issue is with *throwing* the exception, not catching it.